# Creating and choosing arrays for algorithms

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am making a console app in C#, I am starting with this language, so I have some obstacles.
My task is to create an app, that will allow you to pick one of the prepared algorithms and do some calculations with it.
I have to create three types of arrays, random, custom one and predefined. Then I need to let the user pick one of them and use it in others algorithms. 
For example, I need to calculate the sum on elements from the array.
User should pick the array and then press another button to run the algorithm.

So far I have this:

```
    namespace Menu
{

    static class MenuProste
    {
        public static void StartMenuProste()
        {
            Console.Title = "Moje menu";
            while (true)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine(">>> Witaj! Wciśnij klawisz, aby wybrać algorytm! <<<");
                Console.WriteLine("1- Wybierz zdefiniowany wcześniej ciąg.");
                Console.WriteLine("2- Zdefiniuj własny ciąg.");
                Console.WriteLine("3- Wybierz losowy ciąg.");
                Console.WriteLine("4- Suma elementów ciagu n-elementowego.");
                Console.WriteLine("5- Iloczyn elementów ciagu n-elementowego.");
                Console.WriteLine("6- Srednia arytmetyczna elementów ciagu n-elementowego.");
                Console.WriteLine("7- Wypisanie elementów ciagu Fibonacciego");
                Console.WriteLine("8- Ile razy dany element podany na wejsciu wystepuje w danym ciagu n-elementowym. ");
                Console.WriteLine("9- Znajdowanie elementu najwiekszego (najmniejszego) w danym ciagu n-elementowy.");
                Console.WriteLine("0- Koniec");

                int[] tab = null;

                ConsoleKeyInfo klawisz = Console.ReadKey();
                switch (klawisz.Key)


     {
                case ConsoleKey.D1:
                    Console.Clear();
                    tab = PreDefinedArray();
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.D2:
                    Console.Clear();
                    tab = UserDefinedArray();
                    opcjaWBudowie();
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.D3:
                    Console.Clear();
                    tab = RandomArray();
                    //average.Execute(tab);
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.D4:
                    Console.Clear();
                    opcjaWBudowie();
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.D5:
                    Console.Clear();
                    opcjaWBudowie();
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.D6:
                    Console.Clear();
                    opcjaWBudowie();
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.D7:
                    Console.Clear();
                    opcjaWBudowie();
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.D8:
                    Console.Clear();
                    opcjaWBudowie();
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.D9:
                    Console.Clear();
                    opcjaWBudowie();
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.Escape:
                case ConsoleKey.D0:
                    Environment.Exit(0); break;

                default: break;
            }
        }
    }

    private static int[] RandomArray()
    {;
        Random RandomArray = new Random();
        int number = RandomArray.Next(1, 100);

        System.Console.WriteLine(number);
        Console.ReadKey();


    }

    private static int[] UserDefinedArray()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private static int[] PreDefinedArray()
    {
        int[] Array = new int[6] {4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42 };
        return PreDefinedArray();

    }

    static void opcjaWBudowie()
    {
        Console.Write("Opcja w budowie!");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}

Algorithms are in the same solution, in different project files. I'll have to combine it all. 
Can anyone help me to write those arrays and then help me modify my code so it will be using those new arrays?
This is my average algorithms, counting the average of the numbers you'll input

```
namespace AverageNums


{
    class average
    {
        public static void Execute(int[] tab)
        {
            int iloscLiczb = 0;  //Zmienne, wyzerowane na początku
            double suma = 0;

            Console.Write("Ile liczb chcesz zawrzeć w średniej: "); //Otrzymuję ile liczb będzie branych pod uwagę, int32.Parse konwertuje je na int.(liczbę całkowitą)
            iloscLiczb = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            for (int i = 0; i < iloscLiczb; i++) //pętla obliczająca
            {
                Console.Write("Podaj liczbę: "); //Liczby wpisywane przez użytkownika, suma = suma + liczba
                suma += double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Średnia arytmetyczna z podanych liczb wynosi: " + suma / iloscLiczb);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Also my code from the sum of elements algorithm:

```
    namespace sum
{
    class Sum

    {
        //Suma elementów ciągu n-elementowego
        public void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int wynik = 0; //Wynik wynosi 0
            int[] zbior = new int[] { 4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42 };  //Zbiór liczb ciągu, + pozycji, zaczyna się od i[0]=4
            for (int i = 0; i < zbior.Length; i++) //Rozpoczęcie pętli, dla i o indexie 0, które jest mniejsze od ilościu elementów zbioru, i zwiększa się o:
            {
                wynik += zbior[i];   // Wynik  + 4 + 8 + 15 + 16 
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"Wynik sumy elementów ciągu wynosi: {wynik.ToString()}");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

How to change the code so it will use predefined arrays? And I get an error at

> "private static int[] RandomArray() :not all code paths return a
>   value"

Comment: What have you tried to do in terms of providing the predefined arrays

Comment: Well I've created a predefined arrays in each of the algorithms, inside their individual projects. What I need to do, is to create/define those arrays above the algorithms, so I can use them in those and different programs.

Comment: Is it really *that hard* to understand the error message? `RandomArray()` is supposed to return an `int[]` but there isn't any `return` statement in it. Also, there's a useless `;` right after the opening `{`

Comment: It would also help if text, comments, and variables were in English

Comment: Comments explains how some parts of the code works, they are mostly for me. I can change some stuff to english, but those are the most common, easiest c# codes.

Comment: You can try sth like this `return Enumerable.Range(0, 6).Select(n => rand.Next(0, 100)).ToArray();` and `return new[] { 4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42 };` But really the first thing you should do is to complete this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/quick-starts/index

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version for the `RandomArray()` part with hints for the `UserDefinedArray()`:

```
private static int[] RandomArray()
{
    Random r = new Random();

    // define size of array (here random between 5 and 30)
    // so for user defined array, maybe ask user the size he wants
    int size = r.Next(5,30);

    // create the array
    int[] array = new int[size];

    // fill the array
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        // for user defined, ask for every value
        array[i] = r.Next(1,100);
    }

    return array;
}
```

Also please note that your `PreDefinedArray()` should look more like:

```
private static int[] PreDefinedArray()
{
    int[] array = new int[6] {4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42 };
    return array;
}
```

what you wrote with `return PreDefinedArray()` will result in infinite recursive call --> stackoverflow